# How to get device from the kobject

Tags: linux-kernel

In Linux kernel, given a `kobject` object how **can I know** is it encapsulated into the `device` struct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the following [LWN Article](http://lwn.net/Articles/52621/).

In summary

```
struct kobj_type *ktype = get_ktype(kobj);
if (ktype == &device_ktype) 
{
struct device *dev = to_dev(kobj); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again! A little remark about `ktype_device`. It seems that now it's name changed to `device_ktype` (commit 8f4afc410b8d2be49f34835b6bbe788f50471b02).

Comment: @Ilya Matvejchikov, if the answer is correct, may be it is worth accepting it?

Comment: @Eugene: Sure, but how can I do it?

Comment: @Ilya Matvejchikov: just click the tick mark to the left of the answer to your question. The mark should become green as a result.

Comment: I discovered that "to_dev" does not exists, but "kobj_to_dev". Unfortunately it return a point to a wrong device structure! :(